# How to reset your App Engine standard docker image

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm running a small app in a NodeJS14 App Engine standard environment. The app is currently only around 30MB in size, but the version in app engine is currently 530MB in size. This is because I accidentally included some dev dependencies in the final build of my app at one point. I fixed the issue, however, the version size has not decreased since that change.

My guess is the App Engine standard is simply creating new versions on an internal docker image, so that that one time 500MB build is sticking around. Is there any way to reset the internal docker image in App Engine standard?

Comment: Can you try to perform a `gcloud app deploy --no-cache`? And tell me if it's better. else I have another idea ;)

Comment: It is not. The final version size is still the same size.

I also tried deleting the app-engine-tmp files in the container registry and wiping out the various cloud storage bucket files.

Comment: Can you try to clean (delete all files) that bucket `staging.<PROJECT_ID>.appspot.com`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Redeploy your app as a different version
2. Then go to `https://console.cloud.google.com > App Engine > Versions` and confirm that the new version is now serving your traffic
3. Then delete the old version from the same UI

Comment: I've been deploying lots of new versions, but the size keeps growing rather than shrinking. Even when deploying a project where the entire folder is only 70MB including files in the gcloudignore file, the gcloud app deploy results in a new app engine version that's 530MB.

Comment: Did you actually set the version number or you just kept on redeploying your old version? You have to do ```gcloud app deploy --version VERSION_ID``` and specify a VERSION_ID which is different from the previous ones